# Trouble with passing parameters between functions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, parameter-passing

I'm trying to rewrite something I made in Python into Javascript. I'm having trouble with passing variables. It's a word game: variable `newWord` contains a random word from the `words`-array, `random`  is spoken and shown for 2s, after which an input field pops up in `createInputField` and the variable `answer` needs to be compared with `random` in `checkAnswer`

The problem I'm having is that `checkAnswer` is not working properly. Every `answer` is shown as correct. Second, the `wordsCorrectCounter` stays at 1, although `answer` is tested as correct 3 times.

```js
    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    var words = ["meget", "går", "mor"];
    var wordsWrong = [];
    var wordsCorrectCounter = 0;
    var wordsWrongCounter = 0;

    function textToAudio(random) 
        {
            let msg = random;
            let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            speech.lang = "da-DK";
            speech.text = msg;
            speech.volume = 1;
            speech.rate = 0.5;
            speech.pitch = 1;
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
        }
    
    async function newWord(words)
    {
        if (words.length === 0){
            endGame();
        }
            else {
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
                document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = words[random];
                textToAudio(words[random]);
                await sleep(2000);
                textToAudio(words[random]);
                words.splice(random, 1);
                document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "       ";
                createInputField(words[random]);
            }
    };

    function createInputField(random)
    {
        var answer = document.createElement("input");
        answer.setAttribute("type", "text");
        answer.id = "inputfield";
        document.body.appendChild(answer)
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.id = "okBtn"
        btn.innerHTML = "ok";
        btn.type = "submit";
        btn.name = "answerBtn";
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
        document.getElementById("okBtn").addEventListener("click", () => checkAnswer(answer))
        
    }

    function checkAnswer(random, answer)
    {
        if (answer === words[random]){
            console.log("correct");
            wordsCorrectCounter = +1;
            console.log(wordsCorrectCounter)
            document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
            document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
            newWord(words);
        }
            else{
                console.log("wrong");
                wordsWrongCounter = +1;
                console.log(wordsWrongCounter)
                document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
                document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
                newWord(words);
            }
    };

    document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", () => newWord(words));

    function endGame()
    {
        document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "you are done!" + "Correct: " + wordsCorrectCounter + "Wrong: " + wordsWrongCounter;
    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Aliyah's dictee spel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <h1>Hej! Velkommen til Aliyahs diktee!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Random_word">
        <h2 id="Empty">Click start to start</h2>
        <button id="startGame">Start</button>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have update your code snippet. You are not using the correct way to increment the count, you are using `=+` whereas it should be `+=`. Also, when passing the answer to the checkAnswer it has no value hence it is always true.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    var words = ["meget", "går", "mor"];
    var wordsWrong = [];
    var wordsCorrectCounter = 0;
    var wordsWrongCounter = 0;

    function textToAudio(random) 
        {
            let msg = random;
            let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            speech.lang = "da-DK";
            speech.text = msg;
            speech.volume = 1;
            speech.rate = 0.5;
            speech.pitch = 1;
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
        }
    
    async function newWord(words)
    {
        if (words.length === 0){
            endGame();
        }
            else {
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
                document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = words[random];
                textToAudio(words[random]);
                await sleep(2000);
                textToAudio(words[random]);
                document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "       ";
                createInputField(words[random]);
            }
    };

    function createInputField(random)
    {
        var answer = document.createElement("input");
        answer.setAttribute("type", "text");
        answer.id = "inputfield";
        document.body.appendChild(answer)
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.id = "okBtn"
        btn.innerHTML = "ok";
        btn.type = "submit";
        btn.name = "answerBtn";
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
        document.getElementById("okBtn").addEventListener("click", () => checkAnswer(answer.value, random))
    }

    function checkAnswer(answer, random)
    {
        if (answer == random){
            console.log("correct");
            wordsCorrectCounter += 1;
            console.log(wordsCorrectCounter)
            document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
            document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
        }
            else{
                console.log("wrong");
                wordsWrongCounter += 1;
                console.log(wordsWrongCounter)
                document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
                document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
            }
            words.splice(words.indexOf(random), 1);
            newWord(words);
    };

    document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", () => newWord(words));

    function endGame()
    {
        document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "you are done!" + "Correct: " + wordsCorrectCounter + "Wrong: " + wordsWrongCounter;
    };
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1>Hej! Velkommen til Aliyahs diktee!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Random_word">
        <h2 id="Empty">Click start to start</h2>
        <button id="startGame">Start</button>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That is interesting, you actually did not compare answer to random, but just checked if answer is in the array. I did not think about that. But why not compare answer to random? You are using both arguments in the same function anyway, answer in comparing and random in removing.

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well. And I think comparing it with random is good way to go.

Comment: I have updated the code to use comparison, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed that it matters where you remove the random word. I removed it already in the newWord function, while you removed it after comparison. Also I understand passing the answer, it needs the value. Lastly, is there a difference between words.splice(random, 1) I used and the words.splice(words.indexOf(random), 1); you used? The outcome is the same, but I'm guess you have better reasons than I :-)

Comment: Welcome, actually the `splice` method takes the index as the first parameter. If we pass simply random, it does not represent an index of the words array instead it is a string value so first we need to find the index of random in the words array and then use splice to remove the word. I think I am able to explain you the concept :-)

Answer (score 0):

- The problem here is that instead of incrementing like `wordsWrongCounter += 1;` or `wordsWrongCounter++` you are overwriting it always with value as **+1** when written as `wordsWrongCounter = +1;` meaning ***assign +1 to wordsWrongCounter***
- there are still some minor thing here and there that i'll leave for you to play with.

  ```js
        function sleep(ms) {
          return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }

        var words = ["meget", "går", "mor"];
        var wordsWrong = [];
        var wordsCorrectCounter = 0;
        var wordsWrongCounter = 0;

        function textToAudio(random) {
          let msg = random;
          let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
          speech.lang = "da-DK";
          speech.text = msg;
          speech.volume = 1;
          speech.rate = 0.5;
          speech.pitch = 1;
          window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
        }

        async function newWord(words) {
          if (words.length === 0) {
            endGame();
          } else {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
            document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = words[random];
            textToAudio(words[random]);
            await sleep(2000);
            textToAudio(words[random]);
            words.splice(random, 1);
            document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "       ";
            createInputField(words[random]);
          }
        };

        function createInputField(random) {
          var answer = document.createElement("input");
          answer.setAttribute("type", "text");
          answer.id = "inputfield";
          document.body.appendChild(answer)
          let btn = document.createElement("button");
          btn.id = "okBtn"
          btn.innerHTML = "ok";
          btn.type = "submit";
          btn.name = "answerBtn";
          document.body.appendChild(btn);
          document.getElementById("okBtn").addEventListener("click", () => checkAnswer(answer))

        }

        function checkAnswer(random, answer) {
          if (answer === words[random]) {
            console.log("correct");
            wordsCorrectCounter += 1;
            console.log(wordsCorrectCounter)
            document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
            document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
            newWord(words);
          } else {
            console.log("wrong");
            wordsWrongCounter += 1;
            console.log(wordsWrongCounter)
            document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
            document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
            newWord(words);
          }
        };

        document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", () => newWord(words));

        function endGame() {
          document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "you are done!" + "Correct: " + wordsCorrectCounter + "Wrong: " + wordsWrongCounter;
        };
  ```

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

    <head>
      <title>Aliyah's dictee spel</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="header">
        <h1>Hej! Velkommen til Aliyahs diktee!</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="Random_word">
        <h2 id="Empty">Click start to start</h2>
        <button id="startGame">Start</button>
      </div>
    </body>

  </html>
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Do you also have a suggestion for the first question? Why it is not comparing answer and random correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Like you pointed out, there were multiple bugs in you Code.
First you didn't passed the right variable in `newWord` to `createInputField`. I suggest you clean up your naming and store the selected random Word into its own variable.
Later you passed the Inputfield itself and not the input value provided by the User.
The last bug was our counting, but that was minor, but hard to debug during the undefined behavior though the bugs above.

For reverence see my solution below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Aliyah's dictee spel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Hej! Velkommen til Aliyahs diktee!</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="Random_word">
    <h2 id="Empty">Click start to start</h2>
    <button id="startGame">Start</button>

  </div>
  <script>
    function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    var words = ["meget", "går", "mor"];
    var wordsWrong = [];
    var wordsCorrectCounter = 0;
    var wordsWrongCounter = 0;

    function textToAudio(random) {
      let msg = random;
      let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      speech.lang = "da-DK";
      speech.text = msg;
      speech.volume = 1;
      speech.rate = 0.5;
      speech.pitch = 1;
      window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
    }

    async function newWord(words) {
      if (words.length === 0) {
        endGame();
      }
      else {
        var randint = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        randomWord = words[randint]
        document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = randomWord;
        textToAudio(randomWord);
        await sleep(2000);
        textToAudio(randomWord);
        document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "       ";
        createInputField(randomWord);
      }
    };

    function createInputField(random) {
      console.log(random)
      var answer = document.createElement("input");
      answer.setAttribute("type", "text");
      answer.id = "inputfield";
      document.body.appendChild(answer)
      let btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.id = "okBtn"
      btn.innerHTML = "ok";
      btn.type = "submit";
      btn.name = "answerBtn";
      document.body.appendChild(btn);
      document.getElementById("okBtn").addEventListener("click", () => checkAnswer(answer.value, random))

    }

    function checkAnswer(input, answer) {
      if (answer == input) {
        console.log("correct");
        wordsCorrectCounter++;
      }
      else {
        console.log("wrong");
        wordsWrongCounter++;
      }
      console.log("Corret Answers: " + wordsCorrectCouter);
      console.log("Wrong Answers: " + wordsWrongCounter);
      document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
      document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
      newWord(words);
    };

    document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", () => newWord(words));

    function endGame() {
      document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "you are done!" + "Correct: " + wordsCorrectCounter + "Wrong: " + wordsWrongCounter;
    };




  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you have any Question, just leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks, the comparison works correctly. But the words show up twice each time, like 2 times the same. Also, is there a reason you removed the line for removing the random array item?  words.splice(random, 1); I put it there to be able to end the game if all the items passed. Or do you have a better suggestion to end the game? Thanks!

Comment: @OsmanP. I guess your Problem is solve. I have to emit that I haven't checked your hole game. If It is not solved, I can look at it again.

Comment: No problem! This problem is solved, but I'll probably post a different problem, just taking it step by step :-)